# What is the name of this tool -(used for tiling)?

Tags: tiling

I am referring to the tool he is holding with his right hand
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found it using image search by google
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A laser(?) angle finder.  Only saw magnetic ones on amazon.

Think this one has a laser in it, but can be mistaken.

Comment: No the laser is was there before he put the tool there, I am talking about the one he is holding with his hand. I kind of guess what is is but I want that type of level, its generic name it must have one

Comment: More of an angle finder, than level.  Do think it has a laser and the guy is using a laser level also(as shown in second question).  Will edit answer.

Comment: already have two laser tools :-) so no I was not asking about that one